# why executing code in query takes less time than executing it in job

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I have a stored procedure that I run on a new Microsoft SQL SERVER query and its duration is very short, it only takes a few seconds.  But when I copy and paste and the query into a job the time grows for no reason.

I have tried to put in the stored procedure "WITH RECOMPILE" but still the same thing happens.

The stored procedure just copies the information from one table to another, it's very simple.

I need to introduce it in a job because I want this copy to be done every so often but with such a long time I don't see it feasible.

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: So how much longer does it take when you run it using a job? There is obviously always some overhead running something in a job compared to running it directly, so if the time jumped from, for example, 2s to 4s then that's probably to be expected

Comment: Presumably there is some issue with the query plan. To answer this question, we need at a minimum: your relevant tables *and indexes*, your *full* query/procedure, and please share the fast and slow query plans via https://pastetheplan.com. This question is not answerable otherwise.

Comment: Not your issue, but, SQL Server 2008 has been out of extended support for 3 years.....

Answer (score 0):

Check your query execution plan, as it seems like when executing it goes through some full table scans or something like that.

the other reason might be, check if you have indexes properly maintained for the columns you are targeting.